# Having problems connecting to database PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_DBNAME', '*');
define('DB_USER', '*');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '*');
//conection:
$link = mysqli_connect("DB_HOST","DB_USER","DB_PASSWORD","DB_DBNAME") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

This is my code, and I am getting this errors:

> PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host 'DB_HOST'
>   PHP Warning:  mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given

I am a beginner in PHP so I don't have much experience in working with databases. I don't know what to do, but the defines are right.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace

```
$link = mysqli_connect("DB_HOST","DB_USER","DB_PASSWORD","DB_DBNAME") 
or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

With

```
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DBNAME) 
or die("Error connecting to database");
```

You cannot use mysqli_error() in the die of mysqli_connect because $link will be false in case when connection cannot be established to database

Comment: Thank you for your help. I made this changes and now it works great.

Answer (score 3):

Don't quote the constants when using them:

```
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DBNAME)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I deleted the quotes. Now works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Your DB_NAME will have an actual name also

> Identifiers are converted to Unicode internally. They may contain these characters:
>   Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers:
>   ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore)
>   Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF